# How can I copy an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList<String> x.get(i) = new  ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Both ArrayLists should be declared globally

The `x` ArrayList values are: server,buser,paer cook, runner, etc.

The first ArrayList value should be second ArrayList name(variable)

Comment: How is the question related to `selenium`?

Comment: `ArrayList<String> x.get(i) = new  ArrayList<String>();` _doesn't compile..._

Comment: The code you posted is invalid (it produces compiler errors) and it is not clear what exactly your question is. Please edit your question, post valid code, and explain more clearly what exactly your question is.

Comment: Why not using a hashmap?

Comment: yes related to selenium

Comment: @MaëlPedretti how to use hashmap in this scenario can u explain. i am new to hashmap

Comment: @Saravanan selenium is a testing framework how is this question related to that ?

Comment: @Lokesh its related to java

Comment: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/

Also check GiorgosDev comment

Comment: @Saravanan but your question is related to java not testing right ? So why tag Selenium ?

Comment: If you want each entry in `x` to be a `ArrayList<String>`,  declare `x` as `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> x = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to set variable names dynamically in Java. If you still want to give some description to arrays of string you can create a Map for instance.
i.e.

```
ArrayList<String> x = new  ArrayList<String>(); 
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> vars = new HashMap()<>;
for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++)
{
    vars.put(x.get(i),new  ArrayList<String>());
}

...

vars.get("server").add("Some Server info");
```

Answer (score 1):

First `typeof x` isn't `ArrayList<String>`, it is `ArrayList<ArrayList>` because `x`'s element is `ArrayList`

Second, you can't set element of `ArrayList` with `ArrayList.get`, you should use `ArrayList.set`

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> x = new ArrayList<>();

//todo something with size of `x` (if not x.size() = 0)
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    x.set(i, new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,
You cannot create variable name dynamically.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("server", "buser", "paer cook", "runner"));
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

//       if java version is 8
        x.forEach(eachElem -> {
            map.put(eachElem, new ArrayList<>());
        });

//      if java version is < 8
//      for(String eachElement : x ){
//          map.put(eachElement, new ArrayList<>());
//      }
    }
```